# php curl uploading files, problem in : new CurlFile _OR_ realpath _OR_ curl_file_create

Tags: php, file, curl, upload

i want send form with input:file for send information and upload some (2 to 10) files. when form submit information send to main host (form:action) and i do some process on data and i want upload sending files to another host without uploading in main host, so i researching and find CURL way to sending this part for one PHP file in other host and uploading files on that host, and i fund 3 way to send files: (i used for function to detect all send files and user $i for indexes and put in array before send)

1: just use real path : 
`'@'.realpath($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i]);`

2: use file create : 
`curl_file_create(realpath($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i]),mime_content_type($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i]),basename($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i]));`

3: use CurlFile : 
`new CurlFile(realpath($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i]),mime_content_type($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i]),basename($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i]));`

but it is not working and destroy my files to send because i use this code in another server for testing how this works but it is not working

this code is in another server (target of CURL) :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);$i++){
$tmp_name=$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i];
$name=$_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i];
$size=$_FILES['attachment']['size'][$i];
$EXTENSION=pathinfo($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
/*uploading files and insert this information to database ...*/
}
```

but in all 3 way i said, the extension be "tmp" not real extension of my send files; so how i can fix this ?

WAY 1 :
 `for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);$i++){
$PostItems['attachment['.$i.']']=new CurlFile(realpath($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]),mime_content_type($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]),basename($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]));
}`

WAY 2 : 
`for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);$i++){
$PostItems['attachment['.$i.']']=curl_file_create($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]),mime_content_type($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]),basename($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]));
}`

WAY 3 :
`for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);$i++){
$PostItems['attachment['.$i.']']='@'.realpath($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]);
}`

```
$ch=curl_init();curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$TargetURL);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$PostItems);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

i expect in another server (target of curl) i get information from sending files but in all ways the extension of files to be "tmp" and name of files all of them to be "php1234.tmp" and not real my files name

Comment: `tmp_name` is the name of the temporary file that was placed in your server’s temp directory. The original name as submitted by the client is found under the `name` index.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so if i used ['name'] and not use ['tmp_name'] my problem is fixed ?!

Comment: Not in all places, only those where the file name for the upload gets specified. The path to the file to upload of course has to stay the temp path, that is where the file is actually located.

Comment: Nope, i used this pathinfo($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) in other server (target curl) and again receive "tmp" for file extension

Comment: i tested this pathinfo($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) in main host and it is correct but in other server just return "tmp"    :(

Comment: wooooow i checked and fine by all 3 way for send file by curl all of them changing ['name'] and ['tmp_name'] of files to php23213.tmp so i never can access to old name of file when i use curl; how i can fix this to not changing this

Comment: You need to modify the step where you assemble the data to be uploaded _from_ your server 1 to server 2. Of course you get the wrong thing in `$_FILES['attachment']['name']` on server 2, if you _specify_ the wrong name in the step that performs the upload from 1 to 2 already.

Comment: so how i can fix this? please help me about my code please

Comment: Well by using the name and not the tmpname in the part where you are uploading the file _to_ the 2nd server.